# The probability that a company's workforce has at least one accident during a certain month is (0.01)k, read question below

Tags: probability, probability-theory

The probability that a company's workforce has at least one accident during a certain month is *(0.01)k*, where *k* is number of days in that month(say, *February* has *28* days). Assume that the numbers of accidents is independent from month to month. If the company's year starts with *January*, the probability that the first accident is in *April* is........

While reading book I came across this solved example which seem tricky to understand.

**I didn't understand how they calculated 0.31, 0.28 & 0.30. Can somebody explain?**

Refer below image of book question.
[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @CrSb0001 this is problem from book. I want to find probability that the first accident is in April

Comment: Your posting is missing several details.
Please see [this article on MathSE protocol](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236).

Comment: You need to first type in what you have put in as an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have edited the post so that the problem is fully stated (no reliance on image needed).

You are provided (for each month) the probability of at least one accident based on a daily rate and number of days in the month, therefore (using imperfect notation):

$P(X>0|Jan)=.31 = .01*31$
$P(X>0|Feb)=.28$

etc. through April.

This means (since having no accidents is 1 less the probability of having at least one)

$P(X=0|Jan)=.69$
$P(X>0|Feb)=.72$

etc. through April again.

Since it is given that accidents each month are independent, the probability of having the first one in April is obtained by multiplying the probabilities of no accidents for Jan, Feb and March with that of having at least one in April.

The general principle is $P(A\space and \space B) = P(A)P(B)$ if $A$ and $B$ are independent.

That is where the answer $(.69)(.72)(.69)(.3)$ comes from.

While you only asked about the rates, it seemed like a complete answer would help.